# How to deal with heteroskedastic data in nested design, and how to do corresponded multiple comparison?

Tags: r, nested, statistics, anova

I had a set of data with factor A (a), factor B nested in A (b), and replication (r) in each unit. Recommendations have explicitly told the details of how to deal with data with equal variance in R, from nested ANOVA test to corrected multiple comparison (e.g. lme/lmer, glht/lsmeans). But these processes require the homoskedastic data, otherwise the violated assumption about variance may brought about poor inference efficiency.
However, similar recommendations on heteroskedastic data are limited. One of them is the Permutation ANOVA, which calculate the similarity of centroids and dispersion of groups. But directly using welch's anova for data of different groups (e.g., x1=data$y[data$y=='A1'], x2=data$y[data$y=='A2'], t.test(x1,x2,var.equal=TURE) -> p, following a bonferroni corrected p<p^{H_0}/m calculation). Is the plausible process correct?
Another method is the log transformation, which could used to compare means directedly, but only for some data. The inverse standard deviation of the error term for weighted least square was also introduced, but could this weighted data applicable for direct t.test (bonferron or tukey corrected?).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a coding question. I vote to move to Cross Validated.

Comment: Look at vignette("FAQs", "emmeans") and read the last section.